# How Spring @Autowired binds the SessionFactory object even if there is no SessionFactory instance available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, autowired

I'm using Hibernate and Spring with Java-based configurations. My config file is this one:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "dto" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }
```

Working fine. No problem with this, but when I manually try to set the `sessionfactory` parameter for `trasactionManager`, like this:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
   return txManager;
}
```

The IDE is showing:

```
`The method setSessionFactory(SessionFactory) in the type HibernateTransactionManager is not applicable for the arguments (LocalSessionFactoryBean)`
```

So, I created a sessionFactory like below

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.addProperties(hibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory.scanPackages("dto");
    return sessionFactory.buildSessionFactory();

}
```

and passed to `trasactionManager` It worked.

My question is how spring autowired the sessionFactory object even if there is no no `sessionFactory` instance present in the 1st approach?

Comment: `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is not a `SessionFactory`, it's a `FactoryBean` for `SessionFactory`, see the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)

Comment: yes, i missed that point. Thanks

Comment: But how spring autowires SessionFactory bean to transactionManager contructor?

Comment: If you observe the correct answer has not explained how spring autowires SessionFactory bean to transactionManager contructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the method return types from `SessionFactory` to `HibernateTransactionManager`.

This is how it should look like:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
   return txManager;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory")
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true")
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true")
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect")

    return new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource())
        .scanPackages("dto")
        .addProperties(properties)
        .buildSessionFactory();
}
```

Comment: Why PlatformTransactionManager  instead of HibernateTransactionManager ?

Comment: Now im getting 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from LocalSessionFactoryBean to SessionFactory' error ..

Comment: The method buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder) in the type LocalSessionFactoryBean is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: usign 'LocalSessionFactoryBuilder' created the sessionFactory.